# MVC - Building controls in view in Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm passing a list of controls into the view (e.g. information such as - the Id of the control, the type of control, whether it's a required field etc) and am then going to build them up either via the view or through jQuery...but i was wondering whether it would be vastly more efficient if the html controls were build up from jQuery?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i was wondering whether it would be vastly more efficient if the
>   html controls were build up from jQuery?

No, it would be vastly more efficient to use an ASP.NET MVC view and have those controls built on the server using the view model that is passed from the controller to the view.

If you want to dynamically add/remove controls later on the client then yeah, jQuery would be a great choice.